# Efficiently Plot Markers of varying individual size

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

The [`plot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) function allows us to plot all markers with a constant size `s`.

```
figure;
x = -10 : 10;
y = x .^ 2;
s = 10;
plot(x, y, 'bo', 'MarkerSize', s);
```

Suppose instead we would like each marker to have some individual size `sx`. For example, `sx = abs(x) + 1`.

One way to achieve this would be to use a for loop.

```
figure;
x = -10 : 10;
y = x .^ 2;
sx = abs(x) + 1;

hold on;
for i = 1 : length(x)
    plot(x(i), y(i), 'bo', 'MarkerSize', sx(i));
end
```

This works well enough for small number of `x`. However, what if `x` is larger? For example, `x = -100 : 0.01 : 100`.

This now takes significantly longer, while `plot(x, y, 'bo', 'MarkerSize', 100)` would still complete almost instantly. Ideally, we would be able to do something such as `plot(x, y, 'bo', 'MarkerSize', sx)` where `sx` is a vector of sizes with each entry in `sx` corresponding to an entry in `x` and `y`. Unfortunately, that would give an error of `Value not a numeric scalar`.

**Is there an efficient way to plot markers where each marker have varying individual sizes?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is possible using [**`scatter`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html) instead of **`plot`** as follows:

```
scatter(x,y,abs(x)+1)
```